# Unable to build krb5 with clang-6.0 and -flto and Gold: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)

Tags: c, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm trying to build a C project (krb5) with LLVMGold and LTO in order to output the whole krb5 into an inlined LLVM .bc file.

Following instructions here:

https://llvm.org/docs/GoldPlugin.html

http://gbalats.github.io/2015/12/10/compiling-autotooled-projects-to-LLVM-bitcode.html

I managed to get configure to work with:

```
export RANLIB=/bin/true
./configure CFLAGS="-flto" LDFLAGS="-flto -fuse-ld=gold  -Wl,-plugin-opt=save-temps"
```

The `-save-temps` option seems like the one that replaces `-also-emit-llvm` to output .bc. Now, when I try to run `make` I get this error:

```
cc -L../lib -Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -flto -flto -fuse-ld=gold  -Wl,-plugin-opt=save-temps  -o krb5kdc kdc5_err.o authind.o cammac.o dispatch.o do_as_req.o do_tgs_req.o fast_util.o kdc_util.o kdc_preauth.o kdc_preauth_ec.o kdc_preauth_encts.o main.o policy.o extern.o replay.o kdc_authdata.o kdc_audit.o kdc_transit.o tgs_policy.o kdc_log.o -lapputils -lkadm5srv_mit  -lkdb5  -lgssrpc -lgssapi_krb5 -lgssrpc -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err -lkrb5support  -lresolv  -ldl -lverto
/usr/bin/ld.gold: error: apputils: no archive symbol table (run ranlib)
krb5kdc.o:ld-temp.o:function main: error: undefined reference to 'loop_init'
krb5kdc.o:ld-temp.o:function main: error: undefined reference to 'loop_add_udp_address'
krb5kdc.o:ld-temp.o:function main: error: undefined reference to 'loop_add_tcp_address'
krb5kdc.o:ld-temp.o:function main: error: undefined reference to 'loop_setup_signals'
krb5kdc.o:ld-temp.o:function main: error: undefined reference to 'loop_setup_network'
krb5kdc.o:ld-temp.o:function main: error: undefined reference to 'loop_free'
krb5kdc.o:ld-temp.o:function create_workers: error: undefined reference to 'loop_setup_signals'
krb5kdc.o:ld-temp.o:function create_workers: error: undefined reference to 'loop_free'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Makefile:699: recipe for target 'krb5kdc' failed
make[1]: *** [krb5kdc] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/src/kdc'
```

Seems weird as `ranlib` is not required, I tried running `ranlib` manually to each .o, .h, .bc files etc like so but doesn't seem to do it. Any ideas?

```
ranlib: kdc/kdc_util.h: File format not recognized
ranlib: kdc/kdc_util.o: File format not recognized
ranlib: kdc/krb5kdc.0.4.opt.ll: File format not recognized
ranlib: kdc/krb5kdc.0.4.opt.bc: File format not recognized
```